# CommunicationException classes: client vs. service exceptions

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, documentation, specifications

Is there a clear way to distinguish *client* and *service/service hosting* exception?

For example the `ActionNotSupportedException` is likely to be thrown on WCF clients and `AddressAlreadyInUseException` is actually thrown on the service side.

Is there a documentation or blog article describing all kinds of WCF communication exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354510.aspx) and [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396003/23372).