# Which .net exception to throw when the server throws an unexpected exception via webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, exception, client

Which .net exception should throw the client (or better re-throw), if it catches any unexpected exception from the server (e.g. wrapped in as FaultException via WCF, the server can be written on java) to handle it further on client as follow:

- The client shows the user a message about the possible bug in client/server
- The client provides developers the details of this exception (e.g. per e-mail)

Example in the business layer:

```
var client = new MyWcfClient());
try {
  // Try get data.
  var data = client.getSomeData(id);
  if(data == null) {
    // Unexpected exceptions from the server.
    // throw new Exception???
  }
} catch(FaultException<Specified1Exception> exception) {
  // Handle e.g. re-throw.
  // Shows the user the myErrorText.
  throw new InvalidOperationException(myErrorText)
} catch(FaultException<Specified2Exception> exception) {
  // Handle e.g. re-throw.
  // Enforce to show the user some dialog.
  throw new ArgumentException(param, myText);
} catch(FaultException exception) {
  // Unexpected exceptions from the server.
  // throw new UnexpectedServerException???
} catch(Exception exception) {
  // WCF error, like communication timeout, soap etc.
  throw new InvalidOperationException(myOtherErrorText);
}
```

Provides the .net framework any exceptions for (UnexpectedServerException in this example), if not, which exception would you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows the usual exception handling for WCF clients:

```
try
{
    ... // service call
}
catch (FaultException<X> e)
{
    // handle fault specified as [FaultContract(typeof(X))]
}
catch (FaultException<Y> e)
{
    // handle fault specified as [FaultContract(typeof(Y))]
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    // handle all other faults NOT specified as [FaultContract]
    // these are unhandled exception thrown by the service
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    // handle all communication-layer exceptions
    // these are exceptions thrown by the WCF infrastucture
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why catch the exception at all?

You should not catch exceptions that you can't correct. You don't seem to be able to correct any of the exceptions you're catching, so why catch them at all?

Comment: To distinguish the exception hadling on type, e.g. Specified1Exception is the exception specified by server and it is also specified how to handle it. Common exception means for me that is something wrong in the communication, so it's a problem on the client. But unexpected server exceptions are not specified, so the developer must analyse it first.

Comment: Why do you care? Is your caller going to do something different based on which exception you throw? Probably not. You should only create a new exception if your caller needs to take some distinct action unique to the new exception.

Comment: My caller of course going to do something different. E.g. shows an communication error, or goes to login or send the developer a bug report.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the callers will do something different? Will you _make_ them do something different? What happens if they just ignore the exception? If you want a different error message, then just catch `Exception` then rethrow with a different error message, and with the original exception as the InnerException.